# OpenMPI hangs with three nodes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmpi

Hello: I am just setting up a OpenMPI environment for me where I have got three virtual machines set up with passwordless authentication, etc. I have a simple "Hello World" style program complied/linked successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int numprocs, rank, namelen;
  char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &namelen);

  printf("Process %d on %s out of %d\n", rank, processor_name, numprocs);

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

What I observe is when I have the hostnames of the three different nodes in the 'machine file', the job hangs. Each individual node is functioning fine - i have tried combinations of two as well (i.e. any two of the three nodes), and it works alright. So, I can discount the possibility of any of the nodes not working.

How can I investigate this more? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I have added the code. And I have removed "tends to". It always hangs.

Comment: what if you remove the `printf` command and write to e.g. a file instead? (the file should be specific to each process)

Answer (score 0):

printf or file IO won't matter here.

I just added a section about this to the Open MPI README check out https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/ompi/browser/branches/v1.5/README#L1404.  Short version: try mpirun'ing some non-MPI applications, like hostname or uptime first.  If those aren't working, then there's something preventing OMPI's run-time environment from even launching properly (which is what I suspect is happening here).

(get the site's CA SSL certificate if you're scared of the SSL warning you'll get: http://www.cs.indiana.edu/Facilities/FAQ/Mail/csci.crt.  It's the CA from the US Indiana University Computer Science Department; they're our hosting provider)

Have you disabled your firewalls?  Or if you're paranoid, left your firewalls enabled, but enabled random TCP port communication between all nodes that will be running Open MPI jobs?  (iptables is tricky to configure right -- you might want to try disabling it first, and if that works, then try to figure out how to allow random TCP port communication between trusted nodes)

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the answer. Looks like it was a rather silly mistake on my part (answered below).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out (sometime back) that I didn't have slots in my machinefile and I was running more jobs than the number of nodes (4 jobs, 3 nodes). So that was the reason. Sorry, that was silly.